# Nvidia Drivers updated to 20.04.2 while I'm running 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it installed nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 20.04.2 while I was running Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Now I cannot boot into my OS, even in recovery mode.

I've tried changing boot modes in BIOS and not booting in secure mode (On my Asus motherboard the secure boot mode is "setup" for some reason).

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: The details in your question are not quite right.  Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 are the exact same operating system.  The .1 and .2 are just point releases and this is only relevant when installing Ubuntu as a new operating system.  Point releases of LTS releases merely include newer versions of software so you do not have months or years of updates when performing a new installation (since LTS releases are supported for 3-5 years).  This has nothing to do with Nvidia drivers. Please update your question and include more detailed specifics about the exact steps you took.

Comment: I ran ubuntu-drivers autoinstall which installed nvidia drivers, then I ran sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. Right as the install finished, my screen froze and I couldn't do anything, So I rebooted the pc. Now if i boot in ubuntu it says "ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GPP2.PTXH.RHUB.POT4._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_UNINITIALIZED_ELEMENT) 20200528/psparse-529)" and the little underscore is still blinking after this error, nothing else is happening. If I try to boot into recovery mode, it shows me this screen https://imgur.com/a/zDwAsH7 the cursor is blinking

Comment: If you forced a reboot before the installation completed you could have corrupted files.  If you are totally unable to boot into recovery mode you might consider reinstalling the OS.  If you can boot into a recovery root shell prompt with networking you may be able to `apt purge` the packages related to your GPU and then reinstall them before rebooting normally